# 'Assign' 2D block slice in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

Does tensorflow provide a way to create a zero-tensor while replacing a general slice by another one? In particular, I need to assign 2D blocks in a matrix-tensor. Here's an example of what I need to achieve:

Given a tensor of variable shape, eg.

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6],
```

and another tensor defining the slice, eg.

```
[0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 0
 0 1 1 1 0],
```

the new tensor should look as follows:

```
[0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 2 3 0
 0 4 5 6 0].
```

I know there's `scatter_nd`, but it seems like it can only 'replace' values along a full axis. Do I miss any operation or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `assign` on the appropriate slice of `y`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = tf.Variable([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0]])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

z = y[1:,1:4].assign(x)
z.eval()

# returns
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
#        [0, 4, 5, 6, 0]])
```

**EDIT**

Same thing dynamically (here for the position only)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = tf.Variable([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0]])

pos = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(2,))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

z = y[pos[0]:2+pos[0],pos[1]:3+pos[1]].assign(x)
z.eval({pos: [1,1]})
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about using variables like this yet. However, is this also possible with boolean masks or index lists returned by `tf.where`? In practice, the slices will be dynamically computed in the graph. The only solution I can think of right now is to convert the boolean mask to slice indices using `tf.py_func`, but this is far from optimal in terms of performance, I guess.

Comment: Striding can use tensors in place of constant integers: it is already dynamic.

Comment: Sure, that was clear to me. I was looking for a way to perform numpy like indexing with index arrays or boolean masks. Seems like this is not possible with tensorflow right now. Anyway, you answered my original question. Thanks again!