# How to select a "box" within a tensor in Tensorflow and set all these pixels to zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow

### Problem

I have tensors in tensorflow with shape (1, 128, 128, 1). I want to select a box within this 128x128 image (orange box in the picture below) and set all values within this box to 0. All the other not inside the box must be 1.
The position and size of the box must be chosen randomly. Further, it **must** be executed within tensorflow environment. So it's not possible to use numpy or any other non-tensorflow environment.

[image]

I have tried to use bounding boxes. These are drawn on top of the image. Then, I will subtract the image without the boxes from the image with the boxes. What is left, is an image with values of zero where no box was drawn, and non-zero values, where the box was drawn. The problem is, that only the border of the boxes are drawn, so I do not get the values INSIDE the box to be zero...

### Code

This first part is not important - I just grab some random values for the bounding box and shape them.

```
y_min = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
x_min = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
y_max = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=y_min, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
x_max = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=x_min, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)

y_min = tf.expand_dims(y_min, 0)
x_min = tf.expand_dims(x_min, 0)
y_max = tf.expand_dims(y_max, 0)
x_max = tf.expand_dims(x_max, 0)

bbox = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max])
bbox = tf.expand_dims(bbox, 0)
```

This part contains the problem. A bounding box is only a box which draws the border of the box. If I try to subtract them, I only get the points where the border was, to zero.

```
box_on_tensor = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(tensor, bbox)
difference = tf.subtract(box_on_tensor, tensor)
difference = tf.squeeze(difference, 0)
box_binary_mask = tf.where(tf.not_equal(difference, 0), tf.ones_like(difference), tf.zeros_like(difference))
```

This is a poor try to solve the problem... But maybe do the cracks out there better know how to solve this problem... Any suggestion for a new „Ansatz“ is welcome, or a improvement of the one above. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Maybe you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888587/assign-2d-block-slice-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could simply `tf.concat()` a few `tf.ones()` with a few `tf.zeros()` to give the result you need.

Perhaps something like this:

```
def make_box_representation(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, outer_box_width=128):
  x, y = x_max - x_min, y_max - y_min

  inner_box = tf.ones((y, x))

  left_padding = tf.zeros((y, x_min))
  right_padding = tf.zeros((y, outer_box_width - x_max))

  ret = tf.concat([left_padding, inner_box, right_padding], axis = 1)

  top_padding = tf.zeros((y_min, outer_box_width))
  bottom_padding = tf.zeros((outer_box_width - y_max, outer_box_width))

  ret = tf.concat([top_padding, ret, bottom_padding], axis=0)

  return ret
```

if we call this for a smaller tensor to begin with we can see that: `make_box_representation(1,3,0,4,outer_box_width=5)`

gives:

```
[[0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

and so on.

So we can use this produce a (128, 128) representation as described. Of, course, we can make this (1,128,128,1) with a couple of calls to `tf.expand_dims()`:

```
tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), axis=0)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your input, it works!